# GetOrgchart - Changing the height of the box and adjusts the paths on ClickNodeEvent

Tags: svg, getorgchart

I am new to getorgchart and working on a position structure like org chart, I have only seen basic org structure in the demos, I am needing a node that when you click it, it will expand and load the names of employees under the position. I was able to adjust the height of the node when clicked, however, the path didn't adjust.. i tried to adjust the height of the custom theme size but no luck

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>OrgChart | Create Your Own Theme</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum- 
scale=1">

<script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>
<link href="/orgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/saveSvgAsPng.js"></script>
<script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/svg_to_pdf.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/orgChart/getorgchart/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #people {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .get-text {
        fill: #ffffff !important;
        font-size: 60px !important;
    }

    .myCustomTheme-box {
    fill: #FF8F32;
    }

    .reporters {
        fill: #0072C6;
    }

    .reporters-text {
        fill: #ffffff;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .btn:hover #add, 
    .btn:hover #edit,
    .btn:hover #del {
        fill: #ffffff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }       
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="people"></div>
</div>

<div id="dialog" title="Edit node">
    <p>GetOrgChart is more customizable than you think. This is jquery 
dialog.</p>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnId" />
    <div>
        <label for="txtName">name</label><br /><input id="txtName" 
type="text" />
    </div><br />
    <div>
        <label for="txtTitle">title</label><br /><input id="txtTitle" 
type="text" />
    </div><br />
    <div>
        <label for="txtMail">mail</label><br /><input id="txtMail" 
type="email" />
    </div><br />
    <div>
        <label for="txtCar">Car</label><br />
        <select id="txtCar">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </div><br />
    <div>
        <label for="txtHasDriverLicense">has driver license</label><br /> 
<input id="txtHasDriverLicense" type="checkbox" />
    </div><br />
    <input id="btnSave" type="button" value="save" />
</div>

<p><button>Download</button></p>
<p><button class="btn" id="expandOrCollapse">ExpandOrCollapse All</button> 
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,            
        show: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 200
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 200
        }
    });

    var btnAdd = '<g data-action="add" class="btn" transform="matrix(0.14,0,0,0.14,0,0)"><rect style="opacity:0" x="0" y="0" height="300" width="300" /><path  id="add" fill="#686868" d="M149.996,0C67.157,0,0.001,67.158,0.001,149.997c0,82.837,67.156,150,149.995,150s150-67.163,150-150 C299.996,67.156,232.835,0,149.996,0z M149.996,59.147c25.031,0,45.326,20.292,45.326,45.325 c0,25.036-20.292,45.328-45.326,45.328s-45.325-20.292-45.325-45.328C104.671,79.439,124.965,59.147,149.996,59.147z M168.692,212.557h-0.001v16.41v2.028h-18.264h-0.864H83.86c0-44.674,24.302-60.571,40.245-74.843 c7.724,4.15,16.532,6.531,25.892,6.601c9.358-0.07,18.168-2.451,25.887-6.601c7.143,6.393,15.953,13.121,23.511,22.606h-7.275 v10.374v13.051h-13.054h-10.374V212.557z M218.902,228.967v23.425h-16.41v-23.425h-23.428v-16.41h23.428v-23.425H218.9v23.425 h23.423v16.41H218.902z"/></g>';
    var btnEdit = '<g data-action="edit" class="btn" transform="matrix(0.14,0,0,0.14,50,0)"><rect style="opacity:0" x="0" y="0" height="300" width="300" /><path id="edit" fill="#686868" d="M149.996,0C67.157,0,0.001,67.161,0.001,149.997S67.157,300,149.996,300s150.003-67.163,150.003-150.003 S232.835,0,149.996,0z M221.302,107.945l-14.247,14.247l-29.001-28.999l-11.002,11.002l29.001,29.001l-71.132,71.126 l-28.999-28.996L84.92,186.328l28.999,28.999l-7.088,7.088l-0.135-0.135c-0.786,1.294-2.064,2.238-3.582,2.575l-27.043,6.03 c-0.405,0.091-0.817,0.135-1.224,0.135c-1.476,0-2.91-0.581-3.973-1.647c-1.364-1.359-1.932-3.322-1.512-5.203l6.027-27.035 c0.34-1.517,1.286-2.798,2.578-3.582l-0.137-0.137L192.3,78.941c1.678-1.675,4.404-1.675,6.082,0.005l22.922,22.917 C222.982,103.541,222.982,106.267,221.302,107.945z"/></g>';
    var btnDel = '<g data-action="delete" class="btn" transform="matrix(0.14,0,0,0.14,100,0)"><rect style="opacity:0" x="0" y="0" height="300" width="300" /><path id="del" fill="#686868" d="M112.782,205.804c10.644,7.166,23.449,11.355,37.218,11.355c36.837,0,66.808-29.971,66.808-66.808 c0-13.769-4.189-26.574-11.355-37.218L112.782,205.804z"/> <path id="del" stroke="#686868" fill="#686868" d="M150,83.542c-36.839,0-66.808,29.969-66.808,66.808c0,15.595,5.384,29.946,14.374,41.326l93.758-93.758 C179.946,88.926,165.595,83.542,150,83.542z"/><path id="del" stroke="#686868" fill="#686868" d="M149.997,0C67.158,0,0.003,67.161,0.003,149.997S67.158,300,149.997,300s150-67.163,150-150.003S232.837,0,149.997,0z M150,237.907c-48.28,0-87.557-39.28-87.557-87.557c0-48.28,39.277-87.557,87.557-87.557c48.277,0,87.557,39.277,87.557,87.557 C237.557,198.627,198.277,237.907,150,237.907z"/></g>';

    getOrgChart.themes.myCustomTheme =
        {
            size: [500, 200],
            toolbarHeight: 46,
            textPoints: [
                { x: 10, y: 120, width: 490 }
                //{ x: 200, y: 75, width: 300 },
                //{ x: 210, y: 105, width: 290 },
                //{ x: 210, y: 135, width: 290 }
            ],
            textPointsNoImage: [
                { x: 10, y: 120, width: 490 }
                //{ x: 10, y: 40, width: 300 },
                //{ x: 10, y: 65, width: 290 },
                //{ x: 10, y: 90, width: 290 }
            ],
            expandCollapseBtnRadius: 20,
            defs: '<filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%"><feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="5" dy="5" /><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="5" /><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" /></filter>',
            box: '<rect x="0" y="0" height="200" width="500" rx="10" ry="10" class="myCustomTheme-box" filter="url(#f1)"  />',
            //text: '<text width="[width]" class="get-text get-text-[index]" x="[x]" y="[y]">[text]</text>',
            text: '<text width="[width]" class="get-text" x="[x]" y="[y]">[text]</text>',
            //image: '<clipPath id="getMonicaClip"><circle cx="105" cy="65" r="85" /></clipPath><image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#getMonicaClip)" xlink:href="[href]" x="20" y="-20" height="170" width="170"/>',
            //reporters: '<circle cx="290" cy="230" r="20" class="reporters"></circle><text class="reporters-text" text-anchor="middle" width="120" x="290" y="237">[reporters]</text>'
     };

     getOrgChart.themes.myCustomTheme.box += '<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,350,10)">'
            + btnAdd
            + btnEdit
            + btnDel
            + '</g>';

        var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
        var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
            theme: "myCustomTheme",
            gridView: true,
            linkType: "M",
            orientation: getOrgChart.RO_TOP,
            enableEdit: false,
            enableDetailsView: false,
            enableGridView: true,
            clickNodeEvent: clickNodHandler,
            renderNodeEvent: renderNodHandler,
            updatedEvent: function () {
            init();
            },
            enablePrint: true,
            scale: 0.5,
            levelSeparation: 300,
            primaryFields: ["name", "title", "phone", "mail"],
            photoFields: ["image"],
            dataSource: [
                { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "Amber McKenzie", title: "CEO", phone: "678-772-470", mail: "lemmons@jourrapide.com", adress: "Atlanta, GA 30303", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-11.jpg" },
                { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "Ava Field", title: "Paper goods machine setter", phone: "937-912-4971", mail: "anderson@jourrapide.com", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-10.jpg" },
                { id: 3, parentId: 1, name: "Evie Johnson", title: "Employer relations representative", phone: "314-722-6164", mail: "thornton@armyspy.com", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-9.jpg" },
                { id: 4, parentId: 1, name: "Paul Shetler", title: "Teaching assistant", phone: "330-263-6439", mail: "shetler@rhyta.com", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-5.jpg" },
                { id: 5, parentId: 2, name: "Rebecca Francis", title: "Welding machine setter", phone: "408-460-0589", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-4.jpg" },
                { id: 6, parentId: 2, name: "Rebecca Randall", title: "Optometrist", phone: "801-920-9842", mail: "JasonWGoodman@armyspy.com", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-8.jpg" },
                { id: 7, parentId: 3, name: "Spencer May", title: "System operator", phone: "Conservation scientist", mail: "hodges@teleworm.us", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-7.jpg" }
                <!-- { id: 8, parentId: 6, name: "Max Ford", title: "Budget manager", phone: "989-474-8325", mail: "hunter@teleworm.us", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-6.jpg" }, -->
                <!-- { id: 9, parentId: 7, name: "Riley Bray", title: "Structural metal fabricator", phone: "479-359-2159", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-3.jpg" }, -->
                <!-- { id: 10, parentId: 7, name: "Callum Whitehouse", title: "Radar controller", phone: "847-474-8775", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-2.jpg" } -->
            ]
        }); 

    function renderNodHandler(sender, args) {
            for (var i = 0; i < args.content.length; i++) {
                if (args.content[i].indexOf("[reporters]") != -1) {
                    args.content[i] = args.content[i].replace("[reporters]", args.node.children.length);
                }

                 if(args.node.children.length === 0){
                        if(args.content[i].indexOf("reporters-text") != -1) {
                            args.content[i] = " ";
                        }
                }
            }
    }

    function clickNodHandler(sender, args) {
        console.log(sender);
        console.log(args);
        var rect = document.getElementsByClassName('myCustomTheme-box')[args.node.id - 1];
        rect.setAttribute('height', 300);

        <!-- var svgDoc = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]; -->
        <!-- var gElements = svgDoc.querySelector('g'); -->
        <!-- var index = 'get-level-' + (args.node.id - 2); -->
        <!-- index += ' '; -->
        <!-- var gNode = gElements.getElementsByClassName(index)[args.node.id - 2]; -->

        <!-- gNode.setAttribute('transform', 'matrix(1,0,0,1,932.5,200)'); -->

    }


    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
        svg_to_pdf(document.querySelector("svg"), function (pdf) {
            download_pdf('SVG.pdf', pdf.output('dataurlstring'));
        });
    }); 

    document.getElementById("expandOrCollapse").addEventListener("click", function () {
        orgChart.expandOrCollapse(1);
    });

    function getNodeByClickedBtn(el) {
        while (el.parentNode) {
            el = el.parentNode;
            if (el.getAttribute("data-node-id"))
                return el;
        }
        return null;
    }

    var init = function () {
        var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {

            btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {             
                var nodeElement = getNodeByClickedBtn(this);
                var action = this.getAttribute("data-action");
                var id = nodeElement.getAttribute("data-node-id");
                var node = orgChart.nodes[id];

                switch (action) {
                    case "add":
                        orgChart.insertNode(id);
                        break;
                    case "edit":
                        document.getElementById("hdnId").value = node.id;
                        document.getElementById("txtName").value = node.data.name ? node.data.name : "";
                        document.getElementById("txtTitle").value = node.data.title ? node.data.title : "";
                        document.getElementById("txtMail").value = node.data.mail ? node.data.mail : "";
                        document.getElementById("txtCar").value = node.data.car ? node.data.car : "";
                        document.getElementById("txtHasDriverLicense").value = node.data.hasDriverLicense ? node.data.hasDriverLicense : "";
                        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                        break;
                    case "delete":
                        orgChart.removeNode(id);
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    init();

    document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var node = orgChart.nodes[document.getElementById("hdnId").value];
        node.data.name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
        node.data.title = document.getElementById("txtTitle").value;
        node.data.mail = document.getElementById("txtMail").value;
        node.data.car = document.getElementById("txtCar").value;
        node.data.hasDriverLicense = document.getElementById("txtHasDriverLicense").value;
        orgChart.updateNode(node.id, node.pid, node.data);
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    });

</script>
```

It adjust the height of the box, but didn't adjust the path. It has absolutely no effect on the path. Resizing the box just resizes the box, but not the path itself.

```
var rect = document.getElementsByClassName('myCustomTheme-box')[args.node.id 
 - 1];
rect.setAttribute('height', 300);
```

Is there a way to make it like the screenshot attached? Please help, thanks

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW1sg.png)

Comment: you can use details view of getorgchart

Comment: @MuseVSExtensions that isn't what I meant. I have set the enableDetailsView to false because I have called a window instead of the native show details function of the getorgchart. I have edited my post for more details and code i am working